# One to many relationship many working -Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tring to display all jobs related an employer using one-to-many relationship but I am getting this error.

```
LogicException in Model.php line 2723:
Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
```

My code:
Employer Model
class Employer extends Model

```
{
    public function jobs(){
        $this->hasMany('App\Job','employer_id');
    }
}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/find_job',function(){
    $employer=Employer::find(1);
    foreach($employer->jobs as $job){
        echo $job->created_at."<br>";
    }
});
```

Comment: You forget to return the result. Edit your code to this `return $this->hasMany('App\Job','employer_id');`

Comment: You try add relation to both model

Comment: and add with('jobs') in query

Answer (score 1):

In your Employer Model just return

```
public function jobs()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Job','employer_id');
  }
```

And in your Jobs Model return the correspondent employer like

```
public function employer()
  {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Employer');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return the relation:

```
{
    public function jobs(){
         return $this->hasMany('App\Job','employer_id');
    }
}
```